# Can't disable escape echoing even with the echoing turned off

Tags: c, termios

I'm trying to make a more-like application where the user's inputs are recorded but not printed. So I've turned off echoing, and turned off canonical mode to process inputs immediately.

Here's the code for this:

```
        struct termios oflags, nflags;
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &oflags);
    nflags = oflags;
    nflags.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;
    nflags.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
    nflags.c_cc[VKILL] = 0;  /* <Nada> */

    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &nflags) != 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
```

And then to read the input and do stuff:

```
while(1){
    c = getchar();
```

And then I process C as control basically.

So that works for the most part. Except whenever I press enter, while the processing works as expected, the input still gets submitted / flushed. And I get the little square brackets around the last line.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

SOLUTION: Removing 'nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;' fixes it, I'd added that for another reason.

Comment: I don't think it does (just checked). Either way, I don't think it's actually putting in '\n' directly, because as you can see above I have echoing turned off, and that seems to work for everything else. I think what's happening is that it "submits" the last written line somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Removing 'nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;' fixes it, I'd added that for another reason but I can get around using it too.